# signalR client side implementation in ReactJs with JWT Refresh Token

Tags: reactjs, jwt, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

So, I have a working chat app with signal with Jwt auth tokens. I shifted it to Refresh Token now when my auth token expires my my client signalR connection is disconnected and i cannot reconnect because i am not receiving disconnected status or it is being consoled but how can i handle it in my code i have tried connection.onclose() and connection.on("Disconnected") which are being invoked by my server. I need a solution for detecting disconnection status so i can refresh my auth token and build a new signalR Connection. Below is my client side code and ss of console and network layer

**Console screenshot**
[image: console screenshot]

**Network layer event source**
[image: network layer event source]

```
connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(
      `${BASE_URL}/chat`
      ,{
        accessTokenFactory: () =>
          localStorage.getItem("user") &&
          JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token,
      }
    )
    .build();
  const start = async () => {
    connection
      .start(() => console.log("started"))
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("connection done");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, "connection error");
        if (err.statusCode === 401) {
          let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
          console.log("Auth Error");
          RestService.ReAuthenticateUser(user.token, user.refreshToken)
            .then((res) => {
              let { data } = res;
              console.log(res);
              if (data.isSuccess) {
                user.token = data.data.token;
                user.refreshToken = data.data.refreshToken;
                localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
                connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                  .withUrl(`${BASE_URL}/chat`, {
                    accessTokenFactory: () =>
                      localStorage.getItem("user") &&
                      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token,
                  })
                  .build();
                connection
                  .start(() => console.log("started"))
                  .then((res) => {
                  
                    console.log("connection done");
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    localStorage.clear();
                    window.location.reload(false);
                  });
              } else {
                if (data.message != "This token hasn't expired yet") {
                  localStorage.clear();
                  window.location.reload(false);
                } else {
                  connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl(`${BASE_URL}/chat`, {
                      accessTokenFactory: () =>
                        localStorage.getItem("user") &&
                        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token,
                    })
                    .build();
                  connection
                    .start(() => console.log("started"))
                    .then((res) => {
                     
                      console.log("connection done");
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      localStorage.clear();
                      window.location.reload(false);
                    });
                }
              }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              localStorage.clear();
              window.location.reload(false);
            });
        }
      });
  };
  start();

  connection.on("Disconnected", (userId) => {
    console.log("Disconnected signalR");//This is not consoling
    start()
  });
  connection.onclose(() => {
    console.log("Disconnected signalR");//This is not consoling
    start()
  });
```

Comment: The SignalR Hubs API provides the OnConnectedAsync and OnDisconnectedAsync virtual methods to manage and track connections.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.1#handle-events-for-a-connection

Comment: I use my refresh token inside the accessTokenFactory method when starting the hub connection. Your auth provider should return an expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

try to register the [onclose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest#onclose__error___Error_____void_), then refresh the token in local storage.